# compiling visual studio C# projects on 32 bit and 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Visual Studio C# 2008
Windows XP 32 bit

I have developed a windows project using VS C# 2008. My machine is 32 bit. So I have been compiling my applications under 32 bit.

However, one of our clients has confirmed he cannot install under visa on a 64 bit machine.

I am just wondering because I have compiled under a 32 bit machine. Will it still install on a 64 bit machine.

Just some extra questions. When I compile under 32 bit mode. It uses the windows 32 bit libraries. And those libraries cannot be found on a 64 bit machine?

To get this to work, will I have to compile 2 versions one for 32 bit and 64 bit?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 32-bit libraries will be on 64-bit versions of Windows. Generally, you should be targeting "Any CPU" with your C# projects to avoid platform specific issues. You should review your dependencies to see if any of those are 32-bit specific. You can use [CorFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699.aspx) to check each binary's bitness.

Here's a good starting point in the MSDN documentation regarding 64-bit application development: [64-bit Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064.aspx).

Comment: In fact, if you are having platform specific issues, because you have a run-time dependency to a pure 32 bit DLL, you should *not* use "Any CPU", but "x86". "Any CPU" makes your program run in 32 bit mode in an 32 bit environment, and in 64 bit mode in a 64 bit environment, without having the need of two different versions. But this works only if your program is "pure managed" code without any direct external, unmanaged dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

it should work on either 32 as 64bit as long as you are only doing managed stuff in your code...